# Problems with string index in C++

Tags: c++

How can I access the string index in C++?
For example: if I have string variable name test and I want to access it from index number 5 to 9. How can I do that with C++?

```
string test;
cout<<test[5:9];
```

I have try the above method but it does not work. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: [`string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you include the string library, you can use the substr method:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

```
cout << test.substr(5, 4)
```

Just be aware that the arguments are the start index and the length of the substring, not the start index and the last index.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this returns a new string. OP might want to reference a range of the existing string without copying.

Comment: In case anyone runs across this post in the future (just as a fyi), if you are using CStrings the analog function would be CString::mid http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300543%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This slice syntax does not work in C++. You'll have to use, `std::string::substr`

Example:

```
std::string test = "Some test string";
std::cout << test.substr(5, 4) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

There is no slice operator that looks like `[x:y]` in C++.